# How to cache a Resource in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, caching

I am using the following PHP code on an apache server.

```
$func = InitializeA("./resfile.dat");
echo var_dump($func);
echo getValue($func,3);
echo getValue($func,5);
```

Output is :

```
resource(4) of type (_p_void)
9.0
25.0
```

**InitializeA** and **getValue** are provided by a php extension which loads a **.so** file. So assume that their sources are not available.
**InitializeA** internally opens the file and does some processing and returns a resource which is in this example a squaring function. The file contents are fixed and do not change.

Now I am using Apache server instances in prefork mode. Each time the PHP is called it reads the file from disk. This slows things down tremendously.

Does apache provide some way to cache the resource **$func** so that it doesn't have to read the same file again and again from disk to get variable **$func**?

Comment: What's wrong with http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

Comment: @Valkyrie $func is actually equivalent a memory pointer to processed file contents. This location is not available across multiple PHP calls. Problem is that $func is not data but a resource. Can you store file handles in APC?

Comment: @Valkyrie : http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php#106822. Here it specifically says resources cannot be stored in APC.

Comment: Oh missed that note, sorry about that. I remember doing something similar when I was working with resources from `image` commands in PHP but can't remember what I did

Comment: How did you determine that creating a file descriptor is slow and not something else? Caching resources is unsafe, I can think of quite a few reasons why one would avoid it. Alternatively, if your file never changes why don't you cache that into memory store instead of the resource?

Comment: Because I was benchmarking with 10000 requests. The resfile.dat in my case was over 1 MB. So I verified that the file was being read with every request to PHP. It was very slow.
The resfile was created by me with an open source software. So I know it is safe. And I fetch it from a secure location. (Now that you have mentioned I can even chek for md5 before loading it.)

And when I was done with the code mentioned in comments the latency was at max 15 microseconds per request for getValue(). Ofcourse PHP code adds more to this latency while calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a custom PHP extension in PHP-CPP.
This extension exports a class to PHP which contains a static member pointer which points to the resource.
This module gets loaded when the apache thread starts.

C++ code looks something like this:

```
class exported_class {
public:
static void* _func_ptr;
static getValue(,);
};

exported_class::_func_ptr = initialise_func("./resfile.dat");
```

This get loaded once per apache thread and readily callable from PHP using classname.